# What is the exact physics behind the heading indicator?

Tags: rotation, angular-velocity

If I know right, the really basics of its functioning is that a quickly rotating gyroscope's axis of rotation moves into the north-south direction, due to the torque resulting from the tangential component of Earth's angular velocity vector (Coriolis-force).

But I don't know why **exactly** this happens.

Comment: There must be 3 axes of rotation which may be chosen from a variety of configurations (see Euler angles). It is unclear what you are positing. If there is a real effect that you are asking about (I don't believe there is), it is because inertia is conserved.

Comment: A heading indicator doesn't automatically follow the NS direction. It doesn't follow any particular direction, at all, instead it drifts because of changes in the plane's position and its internal mechanical errors. The pilot has to align it every 10-15 minutes using his compass as the reference while the plane is in level flight. The reason why the device is useful is because the compass has a strong error when the plane is not leveled, while the short term direction shown by the gyroscope is independent of the plane's attitude, but navigation with it takes skill and care.

Comment: I may have confused it with another device then, or just misunderstood something. It's not that easy when I have to translate from my native language. Thank you for trying to help, anyway!